# Howto set in the Autotools include paths?

Tags: autotools

I created a learning project with this directory structure:

```
    top_srcdir
      /   \   
    src   build
    / \
src1   src2
```

Directory src contains file main.c with this content:

```
#include "src1/foo.h"

#include "src2/bar.h"
int main()
{
foo();
bar();
return 0;
}
```

src/src1/foo.c contains:

```
#include "src1/foo.h"
//some code
```

src/src2/bar.c contains:

```
#include "src2/bar.h"
//some code
```

Makefile.am contains:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = sample
sample_SOURCES = src/main.c src/src1/foo.c src/src2/bar.c
```

When I change the woring directory to `build` and execute `../configure && make`, the `make` step fails with

> ../src/src1/foo.c fatal error: src1/foo.h: No such file or directory.

What value should I provide for variable `AM_CPPFLAGS` so that this error does not occur?

Answer (score 2):

You really don't need to set AM_CPPFLAGS:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = sample
sample_SOURCES = src/main.c src/src1/foo.c src/src2/bar.c
sample_CPPFLAGS = -I src
```

Should work.